# .phtml file changes won't show, even though my static files and cache are cleared

Tags: cache, phtml, static-content-deploy

So this is driving me a little nuts,

I'm working on a child theme of Luma and the design requires me to modify some of the catalog blocks, so I've copied over a .phtml file into my theme folder.

The file override works, I put the file in the correct folder within my theme, I modified the file slightly to add a class to one of the divs, I flushed my cache with cache:flush and saw the change reflected in my browser.

The issue is that any further changes I'm trying to make are not showing when I refresh the page again, I'm just getting a cached version of my first change.

I've tried every combination of flushing the cache, flushing the static files via the Magento back end, setup:static-content:deploy -f, you name it.

What's going on? I see that my pub/static/frontend folder and my view_preprocessed are being emptied when I use the flush the static files button, yet any changes like adding a class to a div in a phtml file won't show, only that very first time.

I can't continue developing my theme with this issue, what is the proper cache clearing process when working with phtml template files?

EXTRA INFO:

- The site is in developer mode.
- I've also tried saving changes to the general admin settings, such as changing the site name, because I read that forces the Varnish cache to clear, made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution turned out to be running this command after every change to my .phtml files: ctlscript.sh restart php-fpm

For my server, which uses bitnami, the full command is sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart php-fpm

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling this caches in your local:

```
 php bin/magento cache:disable block_html full_page layout
```

flush cache an then see if your changes are showing

Comment: Made no difference unfortunately. I ran the command and it did disabled those layers of caching, as I can see theu're listed as disabled in the admin area. I tried running cache:flush and deleting the static files after, no change. I can make XML changes no problem, and when I add a new template file to my theme for the first time, no problem, but then that template gets perma-cached.

Comment: I have a similar problem: on my site changes in a controller class php file are not working. I have to run bin/magento setup:upgrade.
Very strange, I do not know why.